# C++ Apache2 module not loading

Tags: c++, c, module, apache2

I'm having trouble getting an apache2 module to work. After some time I manged to compile it to a .dll file. I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012.

```
module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA hello_module;
```

It is exporting the following module. However, when I try to load it in apache2 with the following line:

```
LoadModule module_hello modules/module_hello.dll
```

I get the following error:

> Can't locate API module structure `module_hello' in file C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/ Apache Group/Apache2/modules/module_hello.dll: No error

I read somewhere that export decorations could be the cause, so I tried both LoadModule _module_hello and LoadModule __module_hello without success.

Any one has a solution or a nudge in the right direction for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, as a result from tunnelvision and lack of rest time i made an stupid mistake. the structure was actually declared hello_module instead of module_hello. I apoligise for wasting your time

Comment: Thats awesome. I was about to tell you to make sure you actually *defined* the module, not just declare it. Glad you found your problem.